# How can I get e2e test running using nightwatch?

Tags: reactjs, nightwatch.js

I created a test using nightwatch and looks like this:

```
var config = require('../nightwatch.conf.js');
pages=require('./pages/general.js');
module.exports = {
    'stuff': function () {
        pages.load();
    }
};
```

In general .js I got:

```
var config = require('../../nightwatch.conf.js');

module.exports = {
    load: function () {
        return this.client
            .url('http://www.bing.com')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
            .assert.title('Bing')
    }
};
```

When I run this from the command line it runs it twice(?), "load" and "stuff". This is the output:

```
Running:  load                                                                
 √ Element <body> was visible after 163 milliseconds.                         
 √ Testing if the page title equals "Bing".                                   

OK. 2 assertions passed. (5.769s)                                             

[Test] Test Suite                                                             
=====================                                                         

Running:  stuff                                                               
 √ Element <body> was visible after 116 milliseconds.                         
 × Testing if the page title equals "Bing".  - expected "Bing" but got: ""
```

How can I resolve the issues in the stuff part?

Comment: does the website load within a sec? as you have given 1000ms

Comment: I'm posting a complete running answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve your problem I suggest that you pass `client` object to `general` module.
Then take care about the configuration in `nightwatch.json` file.

To help you, I created a complete running example:

I created 3 files `app.js`, `general.js` and `nightwatch.json`

[image]

When I run the test, the result is:

[image]

**app.js**

```
var config = require('./nightwatch.json');
pages=require('./general.js');
module.exports = {
    'stuff': function (client){
    pages.load(client);
  }
};
```

**general.js**

```
var config = require('./nightwatch.json');
module.exports = {
    load: function (client) {
        return client
            .url('http://www.bing.com')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
            .assert.title('Bing')
    }
};
```

**nightwatch.json**

```
{
    "src_folders": [
        "app.js"
    ],
    "live_output": true,
    "tests_output": "test/tests_output/",
    "detailed_output": true,
    "selenium": {
        "start_process": false,
        "host": "hub.browserstack.com",
        "port": 80
    },
    "test_workers": {
        "enabled": false,
        "workers": "auto"
    },
    "test_settings": {
        "chrome": {
            "selenium_port": 80,
            "selenium_host": "hub.browserstack.com",
            "silent": true,
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "os": "Windows",
                "os_version": "10",
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "resolution": "1024x768",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "browserstack.local": "true",
                "browserstack.video": "true",
                "browserstack.debug": "true",
                "browserstack.localIdentifier": "<yourLocalIdentifier>",
                "browserstack.user": "<yourYserName>",
                "browserstack.key": "<yourKey>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does this help you?